# How can I locate text within a list and replace it with new text?

Tags: javascript, list, replace, nodes

I'm trying to write a function that searches the DOM for one text and replace it with another. In other words, I have this html:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to find 'Item4' and replace it with 'newItem4'.

I've been able to find 'Item4' but can't figure out how to replace it with new text. Here's the code inside my function so far:

```
var array = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4', 'Item5'];

function replace() {

  var x = document.querySelectorAll('ul');

  var newText = document.createTextNode('newItem4');

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

     if (array[i] === 'Item4') {

    }
}
```

That's as far as I've gotten. Not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: Do you need to find `Item4` in the HTML or the array?

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified. I need to find it in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you find it in HTML,

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach(function(li){ 
if(li.innerText.trim() ==  "Item4" )
  li.innerText  = "NewItem4";
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
</ul>
```

This is how you do with array

```
var array = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4', 'Item5'];
array[array.indexOf('Item4')] =  'newItem4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to replace.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",
  function() {

    let searchText = document.querySelector("#searchText").value,
      replaceText = document.querySelector("#replaceText").value;

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"), function(element) {

      if (element.innerText === searchText) {
        element.innerText = replaceText;
      };

    });
  });
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
</ul>

Search Text:
<input type="text" id="searchText" />Replace Text:
<input type="text" id="replaceText" />
<button>Change
</button>
```

You could also simply do this, if you use jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("li:contains('Item4')").html("NewItem4");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! We're supposed to use javascript only to make the change without creating new fields, but I didn't specify this. This will be fun to play around with though!

Comment: I just put it as an example. All the logic is inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replace() {
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
 for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
if(li[i].innerHTML =="Item4")
 li[i].innerHTML ='newItem4';
   }
}
  replace();

document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].setAttribute("id", "myID");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this solution. How would I add an id to my list using only javascript? (This is part of an exercise, so I'm only allowed to edit the html using js.)

Comment: @MicahWierenga i have edited my answer. please check it

Comment: Thank you, I like that! (Because this is my first post, I'm not able to upvote, but I very much appreciate this!)

Answer (score 0):

```
//index is the child number(li) and text is string to replace
function findAndReplace(index, text) {
    $("ul li:nth-child(" + index + ")").html(text);
}
```

Comment: I'm just learning to code and forgot to specify that we haven't gotten into jQuery yet, but I'm going to try this out just for fun. Thank you!